# How to recognize if the route was initiated through a history.push or a manual adress change (react-router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, browser-history

I have the browser cache as the central single source of truth.

When I want to change the app state, I just change the broser cache and call setState to trigger a render().

Everything works fine unless the user changes the adress manually (refreshes the window, clicks on a bookmark, etc...), to fix that, I made the router's render method (`<Router render={render}>`) save the url's params `myUrl/:myVar1/:myVar2` in the browser cache too

My issue is that I don't want the router to ovveride what is in the cache unless it was called manually (eg. by pasting a url). Is there a way to recognize the origin of the url change (if it comes from a history.push or another action)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I can help. But I'll share what I do in case its what you're looking for.

This is what I do to keep a hold of the last pathname so that I can have a back button

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";    
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Navigation extends PureComponent {

  jump = path => {
    this.props.history.push(this.props.history.location.pathname);
    this.props.history.replace(path);
  };


  render() {

  }

}

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

The with router package allows us to inject the window history object into any component

Let me know if any more queries

Daniel

Comment: Hi Gadd, no maybe my question is not well asked, but this doesn't answer it at all :)